# Add the consecutive digits of a birthdate recursively till it reaches to a single digit

Tags: java, recursion, numbers

I am developing a numerology application which has to provide a result which is similar to the following,

1 5 0 8 1 9 9 4

6 5 8 9 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 2 2

2 2 2 3 4

4 4 5 7

8 9 1

1 1

2

It has to add the consecutive digits and retain the first digit if the sum is of 2 digits.

I am missing something. Adding a while loop for the length of intList doesn't seem to work.

```
int date;
List<Integer> sumList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the date");
date = s.nextInt();

int len = Integer.toString(date).length();

int[] convertarray = new int[len];

for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
    convertarray[index] = date % 10;
    date /= 10;
}

List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i : convertarray) {
    intList.add(i);
}
Collections.reverse(intList);
System.out.println(intList);
int sum = 0;
int size = intList.size();

for (int i = 0; i < intList.size() - 1; i++) {
    sum = intList.get(i) + intList.get(i + 1);
    int length = (int) (Math.log10(sum) + 1);
    if (length > 1) {
        int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(sum).substring(0, 1));
        sum = firstDigit;
    }
    System.out.print(sum + " ");

    sumList.add(sum);

}
System.out.println("\n");
intList.clear();
intList = sumList;
```

My output is something like,

1 5 0 8 1 9 9 4

6 5 8 9 1 1 1

Comment: What's wrong with your program? Do you get an error? Not the correct output? (If yes please post the error or the output you are currently getting)

Comment: what are you actually getting?

Comment: Indeed a good problem for recursion, but there's no recursion in your code. What's your issue?

Comment: Have Edited the question with my output, Please check.

Comment: I see no need for recursion. Just `while` until `size()` indicates you're done. There's not even a need for a temporary list.

Comment: The sum should again go into intList for the purpose of addition right? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple recursive solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String birthday = "01091995";
    int[] digits = Arrays.stream(birthday.split("")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    recursiveFunction(digits);
}

private static void recursiveFunction(int[] digits) {
    if(digits.length == 1) {
        // Base Case
        System.out.println(digits[0]);
    } else {
        // Recursive Case
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
        int[] digitsProcessed = new int[digits.length -1];
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length - 1; i++) {
            digitsProcessed[i] = digits[i] + digits[i+1]; // Logic
        }
        recursiveFunction(digitsProcessed);
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
[0, 1, 0, 9, 1, 9, 9, 5]  // 8 numbers
[1, 1, 9, 10, 10, 18, 14] // 7 numbers
[2, 10, 19, 20, 28, 32]   // 6 numbers
[12, 29, 39, 48, 60]      // 5 numbers
[41, 68, 87, 108]         // 4 numbers
[109, 155, 195]           // 3 numbers
[264, 350]                // 2 numbers
614                       // 1 number
```

Answer (score 0):

> Adding a while loop for the length of intList doesn't seem to work.

Well it can be done with loops, but it would be harder and messier.

An algorithm with recursion would be the following:

- Init the array of integers.
- Call the recursive function "F" with the array.

From now, the recursive function behaviour:

- Check if the recieved array's length is 1.

  - If it is, print the element and terminate.
  - If it is not:

    - Print the recieved array.
    - Make a new array.
    - Put in this new array the result of processing the recieved one adding as intended.
    - Call the recursive function "F" with this new array.

Comment: Is it not possible to do the same with ArrayList?

Comment: When I say array, I mean any implementation you want. ArrayList will work just fine.